# Change input value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, email, input

The title seems easy, but I need help.

I have a form with a field input "email" of which value is null until the user fills it up. Okay, on click of the submit button, I call the function validate() which is:

```
function validate(){
    var email=document.getElementById("email");
    if(!(/[\w-\.]{3,15}@([\w-]{2,}\.)*([\w-]{2,}\.)[\w-]{2,4}/.test(email))) {
        email.setAttribute('value','Insert a correct email');
        email.style.border="2px solid red";
    } else {
        alert("Valid field"); // This is to test it works
        email.style.border="2px solid #63ce40";
        this.form.submit();
    }
    }
```

What I want to do here is that if the email inserted does not meet the requirements (is not valid), change the value of the input with "Insert a correct email".

If the field is empty and I click submit, it works perfectly, but if I insert text and click submit, the only change will be the field getting a 2px red border, but no text change.

I would like to know what I have to do so that when I click submit the wrong email that was written, is removed and replaced by the text "Insert a correct email".

The input is:

```
<li>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" 
    value="" onfocus="this.value=''" size="40"/>
</li>
```

And the submit button I'm using:

```
<input id="bsubmit" type="button" value="Submit"
name="submit" onclick=";this.disabled=true;validate();
this.disabled=false;"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: **`email.value = 'Retry! You swine!';`** Note, `setAttribute()` is not the same as setting a property on an element (in most cases).

Comment: I would consider using placeholders for error messages instead of writing directly the error message in the input.

Comment: Yes, this is a bad design...you're overwriting the email address the user just typed, rather than giving them a chance to look at it, see the problem, and correct it.

Comment: Take a ook at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15273623/451969) to a similar question the other day. Also, if you're not already, you **are required** to validate userland-originating data. That is the *real* validation (PHP's `filter_var()` has an awesome email validation filter), what happens on the client is simply for the user's sake. You can't rely alone on any other validation.

Comment: Yes, that's true.. but I wanted it to be cool. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Jared, I don't understand what userland-originating data really is... I'm quite new to this, and I'm working on this validation as a class project..

Comment: @user2151981 - Any data that comes into a server from outside the server's complete control or supervision. That is *userland-originated*. It can be solicited (contact form submitted to a script on your site), unsolicited (exe: spam bots trolling for exploitable mail scripts to overrun with their warez). It could be data you let leave your server's control, which then returns. *You have to validate on the server, everything, that your scripts handle, save to a file, query or modify a database*. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15287536/451969). Internet's a bad neighborhood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good that you were trying to use `setAttribute` at all because it's an important method, but the problem is that you don't want to modify the `value` *attribute* in this case, which is a part of the DOM, but you want to modify the `<input>` element's `value` *property*.

```
email.value = 'Insert a correct email';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XJZwm/

Comment: Thank you too, both of you gave me the same solution which is perfectly working. Your explanation also helped, I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: @user2151981 - This is the answer *because it answers the question*, not just *provides a means to fix a problem*. Explosion Pills actually told you something useful. This should be accepted (and you should upvote too).

Comment: Done; I had upvoted it at first for that reason. Anyways I can't upvote since I don't have 15+ reputation. Do you mind checking my code on jsFiddle? you'll see that even if you insert a correct email, it'll say it's wrong... I can't see where it's failing :/

Comment: @user2151981 - Oh yeah, you have to use the `form`s `onsubmit` event, the `submit` *button's* click event doesn't do anything to stop the `form` from continuing the request.

Comment: @user2151981 - This answer demonstrates jQuery event methods and is about disabling the `submit` button from continued clicking, but [don't be the guy in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691054/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit/5691065#5691065) underneath my answer. `:s` It's the `form` event you need to handle and possibly prevent. Trust me. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `email.value = 'Insert a correct email';` instead of `email.setAttribute('value','Insert a correct email');`

Comment: Please consider displaying an error message next to the field, or an alert box, instead of erasing the email address the user just typed.

Comment: Glad it helps, then maybe you can vote this as the correct answer.

Comment: Both answers were correct, it doesn't allow me to vote both :(